# cURL output very slow just on mobile safari

Tags: php, ios, iphone, curl

I'm using the following code to load a large file with about 171092 chars of HTML-code.

On desktop my webpage is loading pretty fast. But when using my iPhone 5 (iOS 9) this outputs takes tooo long... page is loading and loading.

```
function get_data($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($info);
    echo "</pre>";
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
```

}

So In this function i debugged the transfer process with:

```
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($info);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Without returning and outputting the data on my iPhone 5 the request takes nearby the same time as on my desktop pc.

But when it comes to output the data to my webpage its loading and loading and loading ( 5 to 20 seconds).

What could be a reason for that?

Comment: Nothing to do with the curl request then - is the phone using 3/4g connection?

Comment: Using my phone in the same network as my desktop pc

Comment: Ok, so maybe the browser is actually choking on the shear volume of html - to test save the output to an html file, upload it and try viewing it in the phone. If its still slow then there is not much you can do about it

Comment: okay, i saved my curl output to a file and tried to include the file. On mobile Safari it still takes about  5- 15 seconds to load.